# Markdown to clipboard as rich text

Tags: python, markdown, clipboard

Using Python on Windows, I am trying to take a Markdown file and stick it into my clipboard as rich text. Most of the pieces of the puzzle are easy enough.

- Parsing the Markdown to HTML: No probs.
- Putting stuff into the clipboard via TKinter: Yup.

But it's that middle part I just can't seem to crack. The steps I am missing are:

1. From HTML to rich text, and then
2. Rich text into clipboard.

Is this even possible, or is it too big a leap?

Comment: Perhaps the [PyRTF](http://pyrtf.sourceforge.net/) project will be useful to you, provided it's still functional after eight years of inactivity.